# Autowired Class is returning null values

Tags: java, spring

I'm implemented a little service based on Spring. I would like to autowire the class Demo within the DemoController. Therefore I defined the values for it within the beans.xml file. It seems like spring finds the bean because everything is compiling. But the return value of the service looks like this:

> {"valueUno":0,"valueDue":null}

**DemoApplication:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
@Component
public class Demo {

    private int valueUno;
    private String valueDue;
    //getter, setter....
}
```

**DemoController:**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private Demo demo;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/welcome",
            method = RequestMethod.GET
            )   
    public HttpEntity<Demo> getMessage() {
        return new HttpEntity<Demo>(this.demo);
    }

}
```

**beans.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="demo" class="com.example.demo.Demo">
        <property name="valueUno" value="50"></property>
        <property name="valueDue" value="Hello"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Everything is inside one package. I dont get it...

Comment: So you are mixing XML config and auto-wiring via annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have annotated `Demo` as a `@Component`. Therefore, Spring instantiates a bean of this class using its default constructor during the component scan (you have enabled it with `@ComponentScan({"com"})`), and then injects (autowires) it into `DemoController`. So, the autowired bean not the one defined in `beans.xml`.

There are 2 ways to solve the issue:

1) If you want to go with XML configuration, remove `@Component` from `Demo` class, and add `@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")` annotation to your Controller class.

2) If you want to go with JavaConfig (annotations), you would need to add separate class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Demo demo() {
        return new Demo(50, "Hello"); // or initialize using setters
    }
}
```

...and add `@Import(MyConfiguration.class)` annotation to your Controller class, and remove `@Component` from `Demo` class.

Comment: Hence the solution would be to ditch xml declaration and create a constructor with no parameters to set the fields to the default values he wants to use

Comment: Added possible solutions to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As a solution to what @PresentProgrammer said, you can move your XML configuration to a Java configuration as following:

```
    @Bean
    public Demo demo() {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.setValueUno(50);
        demo.setValueDue("Hello");
        return demo;
    }
```

You can add this configuration directly to the `DemoApplication` class or to a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    //Bean Configurations

}
```

For further details, you can read [Java-based container configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s11.html) Spring documentation.

Comment: Ok I get that. But what if I would like to use the xml file for defining the values? Seems like spring is not able to find the file.